# Appropriate sentence about decision making in past

Tags: american-english

1. One year ago on this very day, I made a very important decision.
2. One year ago on this very day, I decided a very important decision.

Which one will be perfect?

Comment: I believe they (can) say "to take a decision" in the UK, but for us Americans, it's always "to make a decision".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Decisions** are **made**, they are not **decided**.

The verb "**decide**" does have **transitive** senses, but they are not really applicable here.  See, for instance, [this dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/decide), for examples.

There are some idioms in English where we use the same (or similar) word for the verb and its subject, like

> "If you're going to **talk** the **talk**, you've got to **walk** the **walk**" (*meaning: practice what you preach*)
>   "**fight** the **fight**"
>   "**teach** the **teacher**"

but "**decide** a **decision**" is not one of them.

Answer (score 4):

The first one is better. The second one is unnatural.

If the decision was to take some course of action (that is, to *do* something), the second one can be changed to

> One year ago on this very day, I decided to do something very important.

and it will be just as good as your Sentence 1.